# How to check remote IP and Port is available?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, networking, tcp

I have to check remote IP and Port is available or not.If its is available it will move to next form.If not available it should come to the initial state.I tried using this

```
while (true)
{
    IPGlobalProperties ipProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
    IPEndPoint[] ipEndPoints = ipProperties.GetActiveTcpListeners();
    -------
    -------
    -------
}
```

I am showing the example coding.it was checking local IP and port and moving to next form.it will check local port and IP is available.if port and IP not available it will come to the initial stage and it was working fine.same thing i have to check in remote Port and IP.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the `Ping` class of .NET to find out if the system is up and connected, the use the  `PortScanner` to check if the port is open. check these links for further reading and exploring.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8e4410bd-307f-4264-9575-cd9882653945/help-with-portscanner-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

OR

```
public static bool PingHost(string hostUri, int portNumber)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new TcpClient(hostUri, portNumber))
            return true;
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error pinging host:'" + hostUri + ":" + portNumber.ToString() + "'");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for! Just one Idea: `TcpClient` implements `IDisposable` so you could do it like this: `using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(_adress, port))
                {
                    return true;
                }`

Comment: It didn't work for me =(
Ping only ip = works in the code;
ping ip with port = works in online tool.