# How would I check to see if website a is online

Tags: c#, networking

So, I know it's possible to ping a server, with Ping.Send(string) in c#, but would it be possible to ping a specific web application, instead of the whole server. For example, there is a server with three websites (a, b, and c) hosted on it. The server IP is 1.1.1.1. Each of the websites has a different port. How would I check to see if website a is currently being hosted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check remote IP and Port is available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903861/how-to-check-remote-ip-and-port-is-available). The second method is probably what you want.

Comment: Define "online" very precisely and then test whether it meets that definition. For example, if you decide that "online" means that you can get the landing page, then try to get the landing page and see if you succeed.

Comment: @Coral what do they mean by available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make a request to WebSite

```
private bool PingWebSite(string url)
{
    try
    {
        WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then use it

```
var isWebSiteWorking = PingWebSite("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldnt do the GetResponse() because, what if that particular Url is returning you a 1+ GB of file, this will block your application. Just making the head request should be sufficient  or using TcpClient.

```
async Task<Boolean> IsAvailable()
{
    string url = "http://www.google.com";
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, url);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                response.Dump();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the TcpClient, cause it worked the best for what I was trying to do.